# XSD uniqueness constraint

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to generate an XSD for the below sample xml file. The idea is to generate this file and validate it as part of an automation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomLabels
    xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <labels>
        <fullName>Label1</fullName>
        <categories>L1</categories>
        <language>en_US</language>
        <protected>false</protected>
        <shortDescription>This is label 1</shortDescription>
        <value>1</value>
    </labels>
    <labels>
        <fullName>Label2</fullName>
        <categories>L2</categories>
        <language>en_US</language>
        <protected>false</protected>
        <shortDescription>Label 2 </shortDescription>
        <value>2</value>
    </labels>
        <labels>
        <fullName>Label2</fullName>
        <categories>L2</categories>
        <language>en_US</language>
        <protected>false</protected>
        <shortDescription>New label</shortDescription>
        <value>New value</value>
    </labels>
</CustomLabels>
```

The xsd I've generated so far is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"
           targetNamespace="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

  <xs:element name="CustomLabels">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="labels">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="fullName" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="categories" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element name="language" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="protected" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element name="shortDescription" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="fullname_unique">
            <xs:selector xpath="labels/fullName"/>
            <xs:field xpath="."/>
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I've put a uniqueness check for fullName, however this doesn't seem to work somehow. Can someone explain what's the problem here and guide on how to acheive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your elements are in a namespace and the XPath expressions need to reflect this. Use `<xs:selector xpath="p:labels/p:fullName"/>` and add `xmlns:p="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata"` to the `xs:schema` element.